# What does "Line endings must be a Carriage Return/Line Feed (CRLF) pair" mean?

Tags: icalendar

I used http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx link to validate the link of my calendar. And i got the warning "Line endings must be a Carriage Return/Line Feed (CRLF) pair.". What does this mean? What do I need to this to remove this warning. Can anyone please help me on this issues.
Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Or the answers weren't sufficient :)

Comment: What nightcracker said. This isn't a game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means the file has to be in "Windows" format, rather than UNIX format. If you're creating the file from code, it means that you need to write "\r\n" at the end of the lines, rather than just "\n" -- assuming you're using some language where that makes sense, of course. If you're creating the file by hand, save it in "DOS mode" from your editor.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are running a Linux or Mac OS X box, which uses just the LF (line feed) ASCII value for line endings.

Windows uses CRLF (carriage return; line feed) for line endings.

You must convert this, for example with Notepad++ (though dedicated application exist).

Answer (score 0):

tr -d '\r' < userlist.txt > newlist.txt